# Pre-create controls before they are actually called

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, controls

I have some heavy forms that take quite a while to be created then loaded. Is it possible to save the creation time by creating the form asynchronously, then on the UI thread, instead of calling a `new MyControl()` use the pre-instantiated form instead?

I know that `BackgroundWorker` isn't suggested for that but once my app is loaded with the initial view, it would really help a lot to gain time (well memory is of course another issue, but for now that's secondary)...

Comment: You need to create winforms controls on the UI thread. Is it the actual building of the form, or the loading of the data that takes a long time? You could separate out the non-ui work and do *that* on another thread..

Comment: @Blorgbeard The data loading etc is actually not the biggest issue, I have complex forms taking some time to be created THEN loaded - but the loading is slow because of complex layout, not data loading...

Comment: @Blorgbeard also forgot to mention: I talk specifically about `UserControl` items that are then inflated to a main `Form` - does it make any difference?

Comment: "inflated"? I think this is going to be hard to answer without more details about what kind of work is involved in building these controls. Make sure you're not performing layout more than once - run a profiler and check your function don't get called more than expected, and don't redraw until you're finished (if you're doing this while the form is visible).